# Language for finding a function to relate two tables

Tags: functions, relations

I have two tables

Fiscal period contains the numbers 1-12
Actual period contains the same sequence

However, they are related so that

Fiscal Period 1 = Actual Period 4

and

AP 1 = FP 10

I'm looking for either a formula to convert the number, or the terminology so I can properly search google. More out of curiosity than anything really

A logical way to put it would be `AP=IF(FP>=10, |True|FP-9, |False| FP+3)`

As a visual aid:

FP-Period Name-AP

1   = April =    4

2   = May   =5

3   = June  =6

4   = July =    7

5   = August    = 8

6   = September = 9

7   = October = 10

8   = November =    11

9   = December =    12

10  = January=  1

11 = February   = 2

12  = March = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

if $n=aq+r$ with $n,a,q,r\in\mathbb{Z}$, then we say $n\equiv r\mod q$

This returns a value in $\{0,\dots,q-1\}$.

So $(FP+3)\mod12$ almost works, expect for December returns $0$.

To fix this, we can split the $+3$ into two bits:

$$AP=(FP+2)\mod12+1$$